# Какие файлы workspace Eclipse можно не включить в контроль версий?

Tags: eclipse, svn

Имеется workspace в Eclipse(Xilinx SDK - это среда на основе Elcipse). В ней 4 прокта. В каталоге Workspace также создан каталог .metadata. Весь каталог в системе SVN. В этой папке .metadata постоянно генерируется большое кол-во непонятных файлов. Какие из них можно исключить из контроля версий?

Comment: в идеале всё, что пишете не вы, не должно быть в системе контроля версий (кроме результатов кодогенерации)

Comment: В идеале да. А в реале?

Comment: В реале это зависит от языка, платформы и используемых инструментов в каждом конкретном случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, как это делается в SVN, но конкретно список файлов можно уточнить здесь [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io). Как пример, список для [xilinx](https://www.gitignore.io/api/xilinxise)